# Linear operator with non-overlapping kernel and range spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a vector space and $T\colon V\rightarrow V$ a linear operator with $\ker T\cap T(V)=\{0\}$. Then what can one say about $T^2$?
If $V$ is finite-dimensional, then one can show that the rank of $T$ and that of $T^2$ are equal. But in the case of infinite- dimensional $V$, is $T$ a specific linear operator? what propery does T necessarily have? 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not much can be said. Examples of such operators are projections on a Hilbert space, the shift operator $(x_1,x_2,...) \to (0,x_1,x_2,...)$ on $l^{2}$ etc. Any operator with kernel $\{0\}$ satisfies the hypothesis but nothing much can be said about the range in infinite dimensional case.

Comment: Thank you very much @kavi Rama Murthy. This was a mulitple choice test of an exam with the options $T^2 = T$, $T^2= I $, $T^2=0$,  $T^2= T^{-1}$.

Comment: None of these options is true in infinite dimensions as the shift on $l^{2}$ shows.